# Why can't I change `Real Time Monitoring` parameter value in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am learning how to use PowerShell to control a Windows 10  VM for pentesting purposes, the cmdlet `Get-MpPreference` has so many parameters the ones I am interested in are

```
DisableIntrusionPreventionSystem              :
DisableIOAVProtection                         : False
DisablePrivacyMode                            : False
DisableRealtimeMonitoring                     : False
DisableRemovableDriveScanning                 : True
DisableRestorePoint                           : True
DisableScanningMappedNetworkDrivesForFullScan : True
DisableScanningNetworkFiles                   : False
```

Now when I type `set-mppreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $True` I expected that parameter to have a value of Ture but I does not change.

I am running PowerShell as an admin

Comment: Try `set-mppreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring:$true`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this also does not work